# What is the error in the startAction() function?

Tags: javascript

After I destroying 2 fruits by hovering my mouse over them the third fruit doesn't show up.

```js
var playing = false;
var score;
var trialsLeft;
var step;
var action;
var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherries', 'grapes', 'mango', 'orange', 'peach', 'pear', 'watermelon'];
$(function() {
  $("#startreset").click(function() {

    //we are playing
    if (playing == true) {
      location.reload();
    } else {
      playing = true;

      score = 0; //set score to 0
      $("#scorevalue").html(score);
      $("#trialsLeft").show();
      trialsLeft = 3;
      addHearts();

      $("#gameOver").hide();

      $("#startreset").html("Reset Game");

      startAction();
    }
  });

  $("#fruit1").mouseover(function() {
    score++;
    $("#scorevalue").html(score);
    //    document.getElementById("slicesound").play();
    $("#slicesound")[0].play();

    clearInterval(action);

    $("#fruit1").hide("explode", 500);

    setTimeout(startAction, 500);
  });

  function addHearts() {
    $("#trialsLeft").empty();
    for (i = 0; i < trialsLeft; i++) {
      $("#trialsLeft").append('<img src="images/heart.png" class="life">');
    }
  }
})
```

So `startAction()` function is supposed to create fruits. I have images of fruits saved in my folder and I decide which fruit to show by random function and array of fruits.

```
function startAction() {
    $("#fruit1").show();
    chooseFruit(); //choose a random fruit
    $("#fruit1").css({ 'left': Math.round(550 * Math.random()), 'top': -50 }); //random position

    step = 1 + Math.round(5 * Math.random());
    action = setInterval(function () {

        $("#fruit1").css('top', $("#fruit1").position().top + step);
        if ($("#fruit1").position().top > $("#fruitsContainer").height()) {

            if (trialsLeft > 1) {

                $("#fruit1").show();
                chooseFruit();
                $("#fruit1").css({ 'left': Math.round(550 * Math.random()), 'top': -50 });
                step = 1 + Math.round(5 * Math.random()); // change step
                trialsLeft--;
                addHearts();
            } else {
                playing = false;
                $("#startreset").html("Start Game");
                $("#gameOver").show();
                $("#gameOver").html('<p>Game Over!</p><p>Your score is ' + score + '</p>');
                $("#trialsLeft").hide();
                stopAction();
            }
        }
    }, 10);
}

function chooseFruit() {
    $("#fruit1").attr('src', 'Images/' + fruits[Math.round(8 * Math.random())] + '.png');
}

function stopAction() {
    clearInterval(action);
    $("#fruit1").hide();
}
```

Comment: Start by detecting the line where it does a `show()` on the desired fruit. Then debug using `console.log()` why the code doesn't reach there.

Comment: i have tried that and every time i hover the mouse over fruit the trialsleft does not decrease as expected but still after 2 fruits are dropped the third fruit is not spawned.

Comment: Do not edit the answer to say it's solved. Accept the answer by clicking the green check mark instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the function `$("#fruit1").hide("explode",500);`
and `setTimeout(startAction,500);`; both had same time and that's why the `startAction` wasn't executing. I reduced the time of the first function by 100 like that:

```
$("#fruit1").hide("explode",400);
setTimeout(startAction,500);
```

It worked!